# Single onclick function shared between two divs not grabbing correct values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, this

I'm still new to JavaScript and jQuery. As you can see in the example below both boxes have an `onclick` with the same name as well as an alert when you click each box outputting the HTML of the h2.

The problem I'm running into is when you click the second box it alerts the h2 from the first box, not the second. I want to keep the same function and `onclick` name but get a value based off of whichever box is clicked.

I think the solution involves the this keyword but that's where I get lost.

HTML:

```
<div class="divcont">
  <a onclick="getsub()">
    <h1 class="maintitle">First Title</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">First Subtitle</h2>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="divcont">
  <a onclick="getsub()">
    <h1 class="maintitle">Second Title</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle1">Second Subtitle</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getsub(){
    var grabsubtitle = $('h2').html();
    alert(grabsubtitle);
};
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvgEK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right lines.

Avoid inline JavaScript i.e. in your HTML, though. It's messy; better to keep your HTML and code separate. Thus, handle your events centrally. This also brings the advantage of being able to use `this` inside the callbacks.

Your `h2` is grabbing the first HTML found in the DOM as the selector is not contextual to the clicked link.

Try this:

```
$('.divcont').on('click', 'a', function() { 
    var grabsubtitle = $(this).siblings('h2').html();
    alert(grabsubtitle);
});
```

Comment: Missing the closing `)` FYI

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is pass a reference to the outer `a` element into the `getSub` function:

```
<div class="divcont">
  <a onclick="getsub(this)">
    <h1 class="maintitle">First Title</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">First Subtitle</h2>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="divcont">
  <a onclick="getsub(this)">
    <h1 class="maintitle">Second Title</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle1">Second Subtitle</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

And then find the `h2` element within the passed element:

```
function getsub(element){
    var grabsubtitle = $('h2', $(element)).html();
    alert(grabsubtitle);
};
```

Here's a [**fork of your code**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgBFq/)